# AndEngine: ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android, andengine, classnotfound

I keep getting a ClassNotFoundException on AndEngine since i moved a few classfiles. I also reverted those changes after I wasn't able to fix it. Unfortunetly I can't get it back to normal..

Errorlog:

```
12-22 13:55:57.201: D/AndroidRuntime(5527): Shutting down VM
12-22 13:55:57.201: W/dalvikvm(5527): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x411c7300)
12-22 13:55:57.201: E/AndroidRuntime(5527): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-22 13:55:57.201: E/AndroidRuntime(5527): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{de.uni_kassel.repopandroidclient/de.uni_kassel.repopandroidclient.LauncherController}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.uni_kassel.repopandroidclient.LauncherController
12-22 13:55:57.201: E/AndroidRuntime(5527):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1983)
12-22 13:55:57.201: E/AndroidRuntime(5527):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
12-22 13:55:57.201: E/AndroidRuntime(5527):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
12-22 13:55:57.201: E/AndroidRuntime(5527):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
12-22 13:55:57.201: E/AndroidRuntime(5527):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-22 13:55:57.201: E/AndroidRuntime(5527):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-22 13:55:57.201: E/AndroidRuntime(5527):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
12-22 13:55:57.201: E/AndroidRuntime(5527):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-22 13:55:57.201: E/AndroidRuntime(5527):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-22 13:55:57.201: E/AndroidRuntime(5527):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
12-22 13:55:57.201: E/AndroidRuntime(5527):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-22 13:55:57.201: E/AndroidRuntime(5527):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-22 13:55:57.201: E/AndroidRuntime(5527): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.uni_kassel.repopandroidclient.LauncherController
12-22 13:55:57.201: E/AndroidRuntime(5527):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
12-22 13:55:57.201: E/AndroidRuntime(5527):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
12-22 13:55:57.201: E/AndroidRuntime(5527):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
12-22 13:55:57.201: E/AndroidRuntime(5527):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)
12-22 13:55:57.201: E/AndroidRuntime(5527):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1974)
12-22 13:55:57.201: E/AndroidRuntime(5527):     ... 11 more
```

thats the manifest file im using right now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="de.uni_kassel.repopandroidclient"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="de.uni_kassel.repopandroidclient.LauncherController"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Did you set the `AndEngine.jar` in your `Java Build Path`?

Answer (score 0):

Go to project project properties click on android, add AndEngine project which you downloaded from gitHub as library. Uncheck the option "is Library"[image]